# how to display products using Repeater control ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, repeater

i am using repeater control to display results like any e commerce website shows, i mean horizontaly and vertically as well, but my repeater is displaying results in a list but i want it to show 4 items per row then second row then third row, but it is showing items from top to bottom like a straight line list, please tell me what to do and how can i display items like i want them to,i have already seen some answers here but those are not working as well so that's why i am posting my question

```
     <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="span4" style="width:187px" runat="server">
                        <div class="products">
                            <a href="='<%# Eval("ID") %>'">
                            <img alt="" src='<%# Eval("ImageLink") %>' height="195" width=""></a>
                            <br/>
                            <h3 class="title" style="font-family:Pristina;font-size:medium; width:auto;"> <%# Eval("Name") %></h3>
                            <p class="price" style="font-family:Pristina;font-size:medium;"><b>Price</b> <%# Eval("Price") %></p>
                            <a href="<%#Eval("Link") %>" style="font-family:'Malgun Gothic';font-size:medium;">www.shophive.com</a>

                            </div>
                        </div>
    </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:Repeater>
```

The way i want my products to be display is shown in the image, and i am filling my repeater with dataset, i want my output [like these items are displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaFgg.png)

Comment: Please improve the readability of your post!

Comment: @Odrai how to display my products both vertically and horizontally using repeater control like any other e commerce site has products

Comment: you may have to add the css you're using. The repeater itself just repeats  content, I imagine your missing a float or not using inline-block styling in your content

Comment: @RobWhite but if i use any float or anything else the first product itself will move, i want to display 4 items or 5 items per row, will i have to use another item template or alterating template will help? the current code just displays all items like a list

Comment: show us your `css` !! we need your `span4` and, maybe, `products` css.

Comment: @nelek i have not used any external CSS till now i am using inline only, but i am not understanding the idea of how to display them like the way i want, i will have to perform styling only in this div and single item template?

Comment: @nelek if u can guide me then please it will be really helpful

Comment: if you don't use any css what is `<div class="span4" ...` and `<div class="products" ...` and so on?

Comment: @nelek i have just kept these class names and applied no CSS on them, because i don't know what to do next and how to apply margin or float to display them  in a row

Comment: @nelek will i be able to do what i want to do by just applying CSS on DIVS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Wrap your repeater control in a `<div>` and give it a fixed width.
2. Add `style="display:inline-block;"` to `<div class="span4"`

   ```
   <div style="width: 900px;">
       <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
           <ItemTemplate>
               <div class="span4" style="display:inline-block;" runat="server">
                   <div class="products">
                       <a href="='<%# Eval("ID") %>'">
                           <img alt="" src='<%# Eval("ImageLink") %>' height="195" width=""></a>
                       <br />
                       <h3 class="title" style="font-family: Pristina; font-size: medium; width: auto;"><%# Eval("Name") %></h3>
                       <p class="price" style="font-family: Pristina; font-size: medium;"><b>Price</b> <%# Eval("Price") %></p>
                       <a href="<%#Eval("Link") %>" style="font-family: 'Malgun Gothic'; font-size: medium;">www.shophive.com</a>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:Repeater>
   </div>
   ```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: thanks alot it helped me alot, i am getting 3 products in each row if i want 4 or 5 products i will just have to deal with CSS right?

Comment: can u tell me how to add a divider between each item?

Comment: Look at my example it has a separator.I think the problem is that you set the width of the div to 187px but it contains an image with auto width which is probably more than 187px.That's why there is no separator.Try adding width="187" to your image or remove width:187px from the div.There are many ways to do this, just play around with the css a bit

Comment: i have one problem that my border of items are coming in different heights they has the same width but some are up some are down

Comment: Then make them fixed height.Like i said, you need to play around with different CSS rules to get it displaying exactly how you want

Comment: thanks Denis i have got it made, there was no problem with the border i just didn't set the item's height right, thanks for encouraging me, and it's all the game of CSS behind every layout?